# Freeze the activity state - Android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to find a method to freeze the activity state, but without success.

Im creating a game, and I want to add a pause button. When the user clicks, the activity should freeze with the components, and when click again, keep from where it was before. Is that possible to do that?

Comment: Just use the View for this like on button click first time view become visible and again click on it than it become gone

Comment: there is no magic mathod to freeze everything. You will have to implement it on your own by saving (pausing) all timers, saving objects parameters, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the solution it can be helpful for u. As u want to freez the screen for sometime than u have to play with View Visibility.

For it u have to create the view like i have use the **rlView** in my below layout. Visible it when u want to freez the screen.And again when u want to remove it than set the visibility of view is gone..

We can manage the View visiblity like below:-

```
RelativeLayout rlView=  (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlView)

        YOUR_BUTTON_CLICK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(rlView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    rlView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    rlView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Please check the layout:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        HERE IS YOUR WHOLE LAYOUT VIEW


    </RelativeLayout>


     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```